# How to run package.json postinstall script only on macOS

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, package.json

I have to execute this `postinstall` script on MacOS (to fix a temporary bug in react-native-maps):

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "sed -i '' '/Google.*\\.[h|m]/d' node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
}
```

It is not needed on Linux or Windows so how can I execute it only on macOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [cross-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-os) npm package seems to do exactly what you want using the package.json, i.e.:

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "cross-os bar",
  "bar": {
    "darwin": "echo 'i will only run on Mac'",
    "win32": "echo 'i will only run on Windows'",
    "linux": "echo 'i will only run on Linux'"
  }
}
```

So in your case something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "cross-os bar"
}
"cross-os": {
  "bar": {
    "darwin": "echo 'i will only run on Mac'",
    "win32": "echo 'i will only run on Windows'",
    "linux": "echo 'i will only run on Linux'"
  }
}
```

Examples are just from the repo; the naming would obviously reflect your use case, etc.

Comment: It's a good solution. I will leave the question open 1-2 days in case anyone finds a "vanilla" solution.

Comment: No worries, id like to think there was an easier way without adding a dep